# Problems accessing file using database string

Tags: php, mongodb

I am having a problem accessing a file on my web server after restructuring the routes. After restructuring the files to download are stored in the address :

```
http://mysite/submission/uploads/test.txt
```

Previously it was stored in:

```
http://mysite/uploads/test.txt
```

and so the path /uploads/test.txt would work when reading from the database. Iv recently updated the routes as visible in the first sample and have updated the content in the mongodb database. However as the uploads folder is in root and the download.php file is in the submission folder the path from the database im assuming points to:

```
http://mysite/mydownloadpage/submission/uploads/test.txt
```

in my database it contains the text to the path exactly as follows:

```
submission/uploads/test.txt
```

I tried to append the prefix to the string to point up a directory back to root, but it does not function:

```
../submission/uploads/test.txt
```

This seems to result in it including the '..' instead of pointing it to the root directory.

Here is the download function which gets passed the path from the database:

```
function download($path){

if(!file_exists($path)){
die('Error');
}else{
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($path));
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
ob_start();
flush();
readfile($path);
exit;
}
}
if (isset($_GET['download'])) {
if (!empty($_GET['download'])) {
$file = $_GET['download'];
download($file);
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to reference that directory.So, somewhere, you need to define the root directory. What does `echo getcwd();` return? And what does your directory structure look like?

Comment: That returns the directory of whatever php file i add it too. i.e  http://mysite/download/ or http://mysite/submission/ which might be helpful but im trying to donwload from a different directory so download.php is in http://mysite/download/ and the files are in http://mysite/submission/uploads

Comment: What I (*and many others*) do is this: `DEFINE('ROOT', getcwd() . DS);` on the very root `index.php` file. Once a root is defined, you can simply reference it with appropriate directory structures to achieve what you're doing: `$path = ROOT . '/submission/uploads/' . $the_file_name;` (*as an example*). Other than that, you need to reference that absolute path - what I've supplied is common practice, keeping it all uniform and aligned.

Comment: Ok that seemed extremely useful but it points to the address on the web server itself C:\apache\htdocs\mysite\submission\uploads\tes.txt and still wasnt accessible somehow.....

Comment: Alright, so we can find the files just fine (*that's good!*). Now we need to see if there are permission errors (*or any other errors*) preventing you from downloading the file. Can you put this at the top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` and let me know if anything shows up after testing.

Comment: I receive a similar error as before :Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: Are you sure that the files are actually present in that directory on your server? Just jump onto a FTP client to confirm :-)

Comment: im sure i can actully view the text files in the browser by just entering  http://mysite/submission/uploads/test.txt

Comment: Alrighty, can you do the following for me: `echo file_get_contents($path);` and let me know if anything shows up. Also, you've got this: `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));` yet I don't see a `$file` defined anywhere. Maybe change that to `$path` and see what happens? **ALSO**, you need to define your function properly: `function download($file) { ...` (*you missed the arguments*)

Comment: ah ok correct the file thing and echo file_get_contents($path); just makes my page freeze for no apparent reason, all my links become frozen and jquery throws an error '500' internal server error warning

Comment: Okay, check what your PHP error logs show update your OP with the errors shown. Also, what's the jquery being used for?

Comment: They all complain of missing files showing only the first half of the url : /submission/uploads/test.txt which is from the databse or an unformatted version from testing the samples earlier : C:\apache\htdocs\Sitesubmission/uploads/test.txt but im unsure where the Site part came from

Comment: That site might be the directory your files are in? In any case, I take it you're doing something like `$path = ROOT . $my_path_from_db;` right? Well just chuck a directory separator in there: `ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $my_path_from_db;` :-)

Comment: That worked! perfectly thanks so much for taking the time to help! if you wanna copy and send an answer in i'll mark it as the answer to this question :) thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, glad we finally got it sorted! A common practice is to define a `ROOT`/`ROOT_PATH`/etc constant that you can reference globally for all inclusions like you require. This is usually done in the root `index.php` file with:

```
DEFINE('ROOT', getcwd());
```

Now, there are a few issues in your current function definition. You need to supply the arguments if you want to use them. You can resolve this by amending it to:

```
function download($file) { ...
                  ^^^^^--- we added this.
```

Now, when defining your file, you need to specify the absolute path:

```
$path = ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $my_path_from_db;
```

And you should note that `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is an internal PHP defined constant which represents `\` or `/` depending on operating system :).

Comment: Works perfectly! thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: @Dean219 My pleasure - glad I could help you solve it :)